# How do I set the IPN URL in the new PayPal website?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

It's been 2 days now that I'm working on my PHP application which processes IPN notifications. Now that it's mostly finished I want to test it. So I go to my personal account and create a button. The problem is that I just don't see any field to enter my IPN URL. I've searched the WEB for an answer but most answers refer only to the old website by going to my profile -> my selling tool. I just don't see anything IPN related. Please help this is very frustrating.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Profile menu (or Settings) -> Selling preferences -> Instant Payment Notification preferences

But currently PayPal are updating or something and everything is very confusing, slow and frustrating. So there could be some problem with your account or the option is present only on some types of business accounts (for example the one I am looking at the moment is an Express Checkout for Digital goods)

If you can't find the option in the menu - just contact PayPal support here https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/helpcenter/helphub/home/